# Row count where column1='value1' and column1='value2' group by column2

Tags: mysql, postgresql, count, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
date         day     weather
2000-01-01   Monday  Sunny
2000-01-02   Tuesday Rainy
```

. . .

I want to get number of rainy Mondays and sunny Mondays in one query like

```
day     rainy_d  sunny_d
Monday  2        5
```

How to accomplish that in Mysql and PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select `Day`, 
SUM(case when weather = 'Sunny' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Sunny_D,
SUM(case when weather = 'Rainy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Rainy_D
FROM YOURTABLENAME
Where day = 'Monday'
Group by `Day`
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL, works in both:

```
SELECT
    day,
    SUM(CASE WHEN weather = 'Rainy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rainy_d,
    SUM(CASE WHEN weather = 'Sunny' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sunny_d
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY day
```

More concise version - MySQL only:

```
SELECT
    day,
    SUM(weather = 'Rainy') AS rainy_d,
    SUM(weather = 'Sunny') AS sunny_d
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY day
```

More concise version - PostgreSQL only:

```
SELECT
    day,
    SUM((weather = 'Rainy')::int) AS rainy_d,
    SUM((weather = 'Sunny')::int) AS sunny_d
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY day
```

Answer (score 0):

The column `day` is probably redundant. I would delete it without substitution. The column `date` holds all the information. Then your query could look like this  ..

In PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT to_char(date, 'Day') AS day
      ,COUNT(NULLIF(weather,'Sunny')) AS rainy_d
      ,COUNT(NULLIF(weather,'Rainy')) AS sunny_d
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(date) AS day
... rest identical
```

The `NULLIF()` construct works for exactly two distinct (non-null) values in the column `weather` and is standard SQL. For more values use the alternatives provided by @Mark and @xQbert.